# Gethomepath not working on iOS 5 / OSxLion

Tags: delphi, osx-lion, firemonkey

Whenever I use the Gethomepath function of Delphi I keep getting Shell Script Invocation Error.

Was this function replaced by a newer one?

Comment: I can't help you since I don't know MacOS, but I'll leave here what is being called from Delphi `GetHomePath` function `string(getenv(PAnsiChar(UTF8String('HOME'))))`. It could be helpful for those who don't have Delphi but know about MacOS development.

Comment: I just realised there was Freepascal 2.4.4 installed on the Mac... I'll upgrade it to 2.6 tomorrow. Hoping this will help.

Comment: Freepascal 2.6 doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas ?

Comment: I finally found a workaround for this: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2011/10/04/39144#comment-7998

So "S := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)); S := Copy(S, 1, length(S) - 14);" gets the job done.

Comment: note that on Stackoverflow you can post answers to your own questions, and accept them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for this:
blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2011/10/04/39144#comment-7998

So "S := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)); S := Copy(S, 1, length(S) - 14);" gets the job done.

Note that the length of S depends on your application title.